# Writing to specific parts of JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x

Is it possible to write only to an object in a JSON file in Python? For example:

```
{
    "same": {
        "var": true
    },
    "change": {
        "var2": true
    }
}
```

I would like to change to var2 to false and keep var the same without copying and rewriting the whole file.

Comment: Not easily. `false` is one character longer than `true`, so you'd only end up replacing the newline `\n`, but trying to change text file content in-place isn't a great idea.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I need it to be very efficient :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open("sample.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

data["change"]['var2'] = False

with open("sample.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```